# Cannot create resource in keycloak - Getting unknown exception

Tags: keycloak

In keycloak admin when I try to create a resource, I get a '500' unknown exception error.  Looking at the logs, it appears a search call is made on the new resource name that returns the '500' error because media type is not present?  I have not done any customizations or set any properties on my instance.

Keycloak version is 10.0 and i've used Oracle jdk 8 and open jdk 11
The full error trace is:

```
08:41:02,795 ERROR [org.keycloak.headers.DefaultSecurityHeadersProvider] (default task-15) MediaType not set on path /auth/admin/realms/MyRealm/clients/6d7c8a64-e725-41f3-a488-9e150eed57cf/authz/resource-server/resource/search, with response status 200
08:41:02,807 ERROR [org.keycloak.services.error.KeycloakErrorHandler] (default task-15) Uncaught server error: javax.ws.rs.InternalServerErrorException: HTTP 500 Internal Server Error
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@10.0.0//org.keycloak.headers.DefaultSecurityHeadersProvider.addHeaders(DefaultSecurityHeadersProvider.java:71)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@10.0.0//org.keycloak.services.filters.KeycloakSecurityHeadersFilter.filter(KeycloakSecurityHeadersFilter.java:36)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.11.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.ContainerResponseContextImpl.filter(ContainerResponseContextImpl.java:356)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.11.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ServerResponseWriter.executeFilters(ServerResponseWriter.java:219)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.11.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ServerResponseWriter.writeNomapResponse(ServerResponseWriter.java:95)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.11.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ServerResponseWriter.writeNomapResponse(ServerResponseWriter.java:69)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.11.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:530)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.11.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:461)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.11.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:229)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.11.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:135)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.11.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:356)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.11.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:138)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.11.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:215)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.11.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:227)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.11.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.11.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
        at javax.servlet.api@2.0.0.Final//javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.30.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.30.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@10.0.0//org.keycloak.services.filters.KeycloakSessionServletFilter.doFilter(KeycloakSessionServletFilter.java:91)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.30.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.30.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.30.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.30.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.30.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.30.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@19.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.core@2.0.30.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.30.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.30.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.30.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
        at io.undertow.core@2.0.30.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.core@2.0.30.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.30.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
        at io.undertow.core@2.0.30.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.30.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
        at io.undertow.core@2.0.30.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
        at io.undertow.core@2.0.30.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.core@2.0.30.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@19.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
        at io.undertow.core@2.0.30.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@19.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
        at io.undertow.core@2.0.30.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.30.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:269)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.30.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.30.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:133)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.30.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:130)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.30.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.30.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@19.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@19.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1541)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@19.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1541)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@19.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1541)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@19.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1541)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.30.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:249)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.30.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.30.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:99)
        at io.undertow.core@2.0.30.Final//io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:376)
        at io.undertow.core@2.0.30.Final//io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Comment: Which keycloak version do you use? Can you post the exact error trace from the keycloak server?

Comment: @XtremeBiker i've edited with error trace and keycloak version

Comment: Which OS are you running keycloak in? Do you run keycloak in standalone mode, deployed in a server, docker? Can you try it with a clean installation? This might be a bug.

Comment: On windows 10.  I'm running in standalone mode.  It's a clean installation.

Answer (score 3):

any idea about the cause of this problem.

Same problem here during creating a resource with keycloak 10.0.1 on mac os with OpenJDK 8 or OpenJDK 11.

here is my error:

```
20:17:05,667 ERROR [org.keycloak.headers.DefaultSecurityHeadersProvider] (default task-4) MediaType not set on path /auth/admin/realms/gettingstarted/clients/c04fd717-4c7d-4e83-8642-e0c621dc8301/authz/resource-server/resource/search, with response status 200
20:17:05,671 ERROR [org.keycloak.services.error.KeycloakErrorHandler] (default task-4) Uncaught server error: javax.ws.rs.InternalServerErrorException: HTTP 500 Internal Server Error
    at org.keycloak.headers.DefaultSecurityHeadersProvider.addHeaders(DefaultSecurityHeadersProvider.java:71)
    at org.keycloak.services.filters.KeycloakSecurityHeadersFilter.filter(KeycloakSecurityHeadersFilter.java:36)
```

Answer (score 1):

Running Keycloak 10.0.2.     It works on CentOS 7.4 bare metal , has the media type issue on MACOS and docker image

Comment: I had the same error when call the external IDP token when running in 10.0.2 keycloak docker

Comment: Did anybody solve this issue for MacOS or docker ? I encounter the same issue, but didn't find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is the bug [KEYCLOAK-14098](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KEYCLOAK-14098) affecting 10.0.0 release fixed in 10.0.1

Answer (score -1):

This is an issue related to OpenJDK.   I tried on both OpenJDK 8 and 14 and had the same issue.     It works on JDK 14 on both Linux and MACOS.  This is strange since I have not found any issues with OpenJDK in the past.